# 'CreateIndexDescriptor' does not contain a definition for 'AddMapping'

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I am a beginner in Elasticsearch. While doing a sample application as like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn904674.aspx , it shows an error in

```
public void CreateMarketingIndex()
{
 this.client.CreateIndex("marketing", c =>.AddMapping<MarketingDocument>
     (m => m.Properties(ps => ps.Attachment
       (a => a.Name(o => o.Document)
         .TitleField(t => t.Name(x => x.Name).TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets))))));
}
```

> 'CreateIndexDescriptor' does not contain a definition for 'AddMapping'
>   and no extension method 'AddMapping' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'CreateIndexDescriptor' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing any reference. 
I referenced Elasticsearch.net and Nest

Comment: Could you verify if the code you posted is the code in your file, some of it is a little off from the example.  See this line `c => c.AddMapping<Marketing>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that AddMapping may have been for the old version of the Nest client. I've been using Mappings instead. Try something like this:

```
this.client.CreateIndex("marketing", c => c
    .Mappings(md => md
        .Map<MarketingDocument>(m => m.Properties(ps...
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me. Also I have a similar error coming in  var queryResult = this.client.Search<dynamic>(d =>
                d.AllIndices()
                .AllTypes()
               .** QueryString(queryTerm));**   Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Maybe try something like: client.Search<dynamic>(d => d.AllIndices().AllTypes().Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(queryTerm)))); The first .Query starts the query portion of the search. Then the inner q is a query container descriptor with which you get to start defining the query. So I'm saying the query is a QueryString query, and then that inner qs describes the query string, with which you can query by your search term.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(mIndexName)
     .Mappings(x => x.Map<Model>(m => m.AutoMap()));
```

or without object type

```
var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(mIndexName)
     .Mappings(x => x.Map(model, m => m.AutoMap()));
```